# Submit Spark job from Windows machine to remote yarn cluster (Unix)

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have set up Apache Spark in my windows machine and trying to submit pyspark job to remote kerberized hadoop cluster (YARN)

I am able to submit the job but it failed with below error

```
19/02/15 17:57:18 INFO yarn.Client:
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: Failed to renew token: Kind: HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN, Service: ha-hdfs:mycluster, Ident: (token for viru: HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN owner=viru@ABC.COM, **renewer=nobody**, realUser=, issueDate=1550233620463, maxDate=1550838420463, sequenceNumber=8415071, masterKeyId=1254)
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: root.ABC.ABC
     start time: 1550233636757
     final status: FAILED
     tracking URL: https://ABC:8090/proxy/application_1549982169433_29638/
     user: viru
```

My spark-defaults.conf

```
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=/opt/anaconda/anaconda3/bin/python3
spark.executor.extraClassPath=/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/jars/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar
spark.driver.extraClassPath=C:\Users\viru\Downloads\jupyter\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.6\jars\commons-lang3-3.5.jar
spark.master=yarn
spark.submit.deployMode=client
spark.yarn.jars=local:/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.3.0.cloudera4-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.611179/lib/spark2/jars/*
spark.driver.extraLibraryPath=C:\Users\viru\Downloads\jupyter\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.6\jars
spark.executor.extraLibraryPath=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.13.3-1.cdh5.13.3.p3163.3423/lib/hadoop/lib/native
spark.yarn.am.extraLibraryPath=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.13.3-1.cdh5.13.3.p3163.3423/lib/hadoop/lib/native
spark.yarn.config.gatewayPath=/opt/cloudera/parcels
spark.yarn.config.replacementPath={{HADOOP_COMMON_HOME}}/../../..
spark.driver.memory=1G
spark.yarn.am.memory=1G
spark.yarn.queue=root.ABC.ABC
spark.driver.host=1.2.3.4
```

I have installed MIT Kerberos to my windows machine and get token as well

Can anyone please help me on this?